# Unable to fire db.transaction on device

Tags: cordova

I try to run this example code on my device and it can only return "Device Ready!". It doesn't seem to run the db.transaction, as it didn't alert the rest of the msg. But when I try to run it on the web browser it is able to show all the alerts and the database results on the console log. Please help. I really don't know what's wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    alert("Populate DB!");
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    alert("Database Query!");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    alert("Success!");
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");


    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
       console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);

    }

    }


// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error Occured!");
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("Open Database!");
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("Device Ready!");
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```